# VS Code - Add a new file under the selected working directory

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get a shortcut to add a new file under my current working folder. So I navigate to the explorer using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> and when I get to the folder I want to create a new class I do <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> which creates me a new file but is not saved anywhere (I'm trying to get a similar behaviour to what ReSharper does for instance).

Is there any other shortcut to get the file created under the folder you have the focus in the explorer? Essentially I could like to get the text box to fill in the name then the file gets automatically saved so that I don't get the prompt later on.

I'm using for reference the following page: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings

Answer (score 415, accepted):

The `cmd+n` command is by default bound to `workbench.action.files.newUntitledFile` but what you want is the command `explorer.newFile` which by default is not bound to a shortcut.

**Edit shortcuts file**

Hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> type `key` and hit enter on `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`

This will open *keybindings.json* file which stores custom keybindings specified by the current VS Code user.

Enter the following in the custom bindings file (presumably you need to enter `cmd+n` instead of `ctrl+n` but I'm on windows so can't test

```json
[
  { "key": "ctrl+n", "command": "explorer.newFile" }
]
```

If you want to only have this apply when the explorer is focused you can add a when condition:

```json
{ "key": "ctrl+n", "command": "explorer.newFile", "when": "explorerViewletFocus" }
```

This way when any other component is focused pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> will execute the default new file command

**Edit using shortcuts UI**

Hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> type `key` and hit enter on `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts`

This will open up the keyboard shortcut preferences UI.

Type `explorer.newFile` in the search to find the new file command, double click it to bring up the shortcut capture modal and press the key combination you want to associate with this command.

Comment: This will create the new file in the currently focussed folder. Is it possible to create the new file from the project root?

Comment: Is there any reason why `"key": "a"` wouldn't work? It works _only_ if I do `cmd+n`

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh This extension will do that for you: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.create-file-folder. It lets you type the exact path relative to the project root that you wish to create a file (or multiple files at once).

Comment: Also wanted to add for others: This answer depends only on the folder focussed _in the workspace menu_, not the explorer as a whole. Was trying to figure out why clicking a file in "Open Editors" then triggering this shortcut was creating the file in a different directory. You have to click a file in the directory you want in the workspace menu first. The open editors menu has no effect.

Comment: Third point: that extension also adds "Create File" and "Create Folder" options to the context menu in the workspace menu.

Comment: I want this to open a new file in vscode (as I would if I clicked on the add file icon with the little plus symbol), not in notepad. I just want to avoid clicking on the file add and folder add icons and just be able to do what they do but with keyboard shortcuts. I was able to do that for the new folder, binding a default shortcut to explorer.newFolder, but explorer.newFile opens Windows notepad. I want to name a new file while staying in vscode as happens when you click the icon. Can I do that?

Comment: Aditionally you can focus into the Explorer with `ctrl+0` or `cmd+0`. With arrow keys you can go in and out of folders and have control over where the file should go.

Answer (score 54):

To add files or folders add the following lines to `keybindings.json`:

*Updated answer on 2020/02/10 (Thanks to @AbrahamHernandez, who provided the comment).*

```json
[
  { 
    "key": "ctrl+n",
    "command": "explorer.newFile",
    "when": "!editorFocus" 
  },
  { 
    "key": "ctrl+shift+n",
    "command": "explorer.newFolder",
    "when": "!editorFocus" 
  }
]
```

These bindings are active if the editor ***is not*** focused.

They are also triggered if the debug window is active. That's not perfect but the context `explorerFocus` is going to be added in the near future: [see GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/commit/e1081a5c4293a650b41c62943d40d507de20866c)

Comment: This didn't work for me: It gives me `workbench.action` not found

Comment: @AbrahamHernandez try changing the commands to `explorer.newFile` and `explorer.newFolder`

Comment: @gregor-woiwode Good news! As you mentioned, the `explorerViewletFocus` trigger was added to Visual Studio Code in early 2017, and it is now fully functional. It may be best to update the answer to reflect that, so that even more people can enjoy your solution. I myself found it tremendously helpful. Thank you for the great insight!

Answer (score 24):

You can use this method if you don't want to create a shortcut.

1. Navigate to the explorer via <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>
2. Get to the folder you want to create a new file/folder in.
3. Open the file picker via <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>
4. Then type `New File` or `New Folder` and enter.

That is how you create a new file/folder without touching the mouse. :)

Comment: I went to keyboard shortcuts (open with `ctrl+K ctrl+S`) and added one for `explorer.newFile` to skip steps 3 and 4.

Comment: I think step 3 should be `cmd+shift+p`?

Comment: @Rafi you are right. I added to the message. Thanks.

Comment: Than-ks. It's worth knowing the shortcuts to navigate through VS

Comment: For step 4, VS code prompt me both `Create: New File` and `File: New File`. The latter is the right one

Answer (score 5):

```
    { 
        "key": "ctrl+n", 
        "command": "explorer.newFile",
        "when": "explorerViewletFocus"
    }
```

Paste it in the Keybindings.json by pressing F1 key and search for Preference: Keyboard(JSON).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wenfangdu.faster-new), it allows you to create files and folders even if the source being clicked is a file.

Demo:

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 1):

Use ctrl+shift+p and search for "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts"

Then, inside the keybindings menu, search for "explorer.newFile"

you can bind it to ctrl+n, and set the "When" property to "explorerViewletFocus", so this command will only happen when the focus is in the explorer

Similarly, you can change "explorer.newFolder" to ctrl+shift+n and the "When" condition to "explorerViewletFocus", like before.

Now you can open files and folders via keyboard inside the selected folder

I preferred this solution to the other ones since I did not have to open that huge json file with the keybindings

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two steps:

1. `Cmd + Shift + E`: Open the explorer with
2. `Ctrl + N`: Create a new file under the current folder and name it.

I actually like this approach than the magical-one-click because each step is clearer and you don't have to configure anything.

Answer (score 0):

As for 2021 VSCode on mac the <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> opens a new VSCode window. If you want to change the behaviour and create new folders using only keyboard do the above to change keybinding:

1. Press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and search for new folder then click on setting icon on the right side of search result.
2. This brings up Keyboard Shortcut tab here you can change keybinding for new folder, click on pen icon and enter your desired keybinding and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try
<kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>WIN</kbd> <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd>
While highlighting a file. Enter file name, double enter. Enjoy!