# How to select a folder in VS Code's explorer view without expanding or collapsing it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, if you want to add a new file or folder under an existing folder, you need to first select it. However, selecting a folder will cause it to toggle between expanded and collapsed, which can be bothersome because it often makes you need to click the folder twice and because it can cause the file list to scroll around. Sometimes I want to select a folder that is already open without closing it. However, I have yet to find a way to do so.

**Example:**

I want to select pktest folder:
[image: screenshot of pktest folder in Explorer, unselected and expanded]

After selecting it, it gets collapsed and I need to open it again =(
[image: screenshot of pktest folder in Explorer, selected but collapsed]

Is it possible to select folders without collapsing or expanding them?

Comment: Check in VSCode settings. Maybe you can change it... if not... suffer :)

Comment: TTvTT @Synapsis I will check it out, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click -> New File/New Folder

Comment: Why do you downvote me, this is literally the answer

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't me who downvoted. As nobody else has answered, it seems that this is the best solution, so I'll accept you. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Coming soon (possibly in v1.51?), there is a commit see  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/71994 that allows the ability to turn off the toggling open/close of a folder when you click on it.   But it isn't in the Insiders' Build yet.  This would be the setting:

```
"workbench.tree.expandOnFolderClick": false
```

Comment: This is now available in settings. (If you search for "expand" it currently comes up on top)

Comment: @ProQ Thanks for the comment, I'd have not found it looking for the setting name.

Comment: This doesn't seem to exist (or was changed). As of VS Code 1.69.0, there's only: `workbench.tree.expandMode` to set either `singleClick` or `doubleClick`.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the same thing. One option is `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`E` to select the Explorer, use the arrow keys to navigate to the target location, and then click the `New File` or `New Folder` button.

Another option is to change keybindings to improve the new file workflow, ndonohoe has [a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39599731/6456942) in a different question describing remapping the new file command.

Answer (score 1):

To just select objects (including folders) in the explorer view in VS Code here are the two ways I know.

If using mouse: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + left mouse click

If using keyboard: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code 1.52.0, they added a [**Tree: Expand Mode**](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_52#_tree-expand-mode)  setting which

> lets you control how folders expand in trees: using a single or a double-click

You can change that to `"double-click"`

```
"workbench.tree.expandMode": "doubleClick"
```

so that single-clicking on folder names won't auto-expand/collapse them.

Do note that:

> ```
> // Controls how tree folders are expanded when clicking the 
> folder > names. Note that some trees and lists might choose 
> to ignore this > setting if it is not applicable.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `workbench.tree.expandMode` setting mentioned in [Gino Mempin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2745495/gino-mempin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73139778/6309) will *not* work before VSCode 1.71 (Aug. 2022) for *custom* tree.

That settings comes from [issues 95697](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95697) and [commit 97646e1](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/97646e138af481ae7ec6bc794806cb88006f1ff8) .

But, as shown in "[How to embrace `workbench.tree.expandMode` in TreeItem?](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-discussions/discussions/88#discussioncomment-3357626)", the `workbench.tree.expandMode` was never implemented for any extension tree.

Hence [issue 158159](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/158159) and [PR 158160](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/158160), release to [VSCode insider](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) today.