# Shortcut For Creating a New MyComponent.jsx file in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to be able to create a new .jsx file with a single keystroke in VSCode. Currently, using the default "new file" shortcut `ctrl+n` creates `Untitled-X` file with no extension, and the file does not immediately appear in my project folder `myProject`, but in "Open Editors".

I'm not sure why this is the default behavior. Hitting the "New File" button  in the file browser creates a new file in the currently focused folder, as you would expect.

How hitting the new file button differs from using the "New File" command in the command palette is a mystery to me.

[image]

What I would like to happen is that with `ctrl+n`, a new `.jsx` file is created. Additionally, it'd be great if the new file could use some kind of template variable scheme. So I'd get something like this when I use `ctrl+n`:

[image]

Maybe such functionality would be better achieved with a bash script?

Comment: you can use the extension [File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-file-templates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part one of the question: [VS Code - Add a new file under the selected working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39599514/vs-code-add-a-new-file-under-the-selected-working-directory), `ctrl+n` can be remapped to `"command": "explorer.newFile"`.

For part two of the question, the addon [Auto Snippet](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gruntfuggly.auto-snippet) allows automatically inserts a predefined snippet when a file is created, or an empty file is opened. So I can run a snippet to create a default `.tsx` react component.

Combining the new shortcut binding and the extension met my needs.

Note: When configuring Auto Snippet, you need to provide the name of the snippet in your `<LANGUAGE>.json` file, not the prefix for the snippet. This confused me at first:

```js
//typescript.json
  "const": { //<--- snippet name to use in settings.json
    "prefix": "co",
    "body": ["const ${1:varname} = ${2:value} "],
    "description": ""
  },
```

```json
  //settings.json
  //runs whenever a new .ts file is created
  "autoSnippet.snippets": [
    {
      "language": "typescript",
      "snippet": "const",
      "commands": ["editor.action.commentLine"]
    },
  ]
```