# Vscode create new folder in current directory shortcut key

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Is there a shortcut key to create new folder inside current directory in visual studio code?

or at least while on the file explorer sidebar?

Comment: I don't understand why one would need this, but you can probably make one, similar to [vs-code-add-a-new-file-under-the-selected-working-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39599514/vs-code-add-a-new-file-under-the-selected-working-directory)

Comment: Use the comand line. mkdir yourfoldername.

Answer (score 5):

1. <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd> to open Keyboard Shortcuts menu.
2. Search for `@command:explorer.newFolder`.
3. Add your own shortcut.

Comment: Alternatively `Cmd+K` `Cmd+S` for Macs/Apple products