# VS Code - Create a file in a specific directory

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am searching for a way to **create a certain file in a certain directory** in my vscode project.
Preferred with a `VScode command`.
For example: A pre-configured default directory that automatically insert the created files with one command.

I found this previous post:
[VS Code - Add a new file under the selected working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39599514/vs-code-add-a-new-file-under-the-selected-working-directory)
But it does not address to create a file in a specific directory.

Comment: @user This command is related to the referred SO post. It creates a new file in the select working directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the extension [File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-file-templates) you can create an empty template with a given file path.

Create a template with the given content:

```
##@@## ~w/src/mylib/${input:File name:}
```

With `Ctrl+N` you can select the template, enter the filename and the file will be created.

You have to create a separate template for each type of file extension.

Or you can create a template named: `placed-file-mylib.txt`

And as filename type: `mylib.cpp`

The file created is: `mylib.cpp.txt`

In the explorer edit the file name: `Ctrl+0` `F2`